# How to add token to each request in each controller- Angular

Tags: angularjs, http

I think i deal with some basic thing but dispite that I am not able to solve this alone.

In [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) I foundout option how to set header for each request. It should be something like:

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
});
```

This looks find if you know token from start as in this example. But i get user token after he login.

So I try something like:

```
login: function(email, password) {
    var data = {'userName':email, 'password': password};
    $http.post('api/v1/users/login.php', data).then(function (res) {
        $cookies.put('user', res.data);
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer '+res.data.token;
    });
}
```

This now added `Authorization` header to each request but just inside of LoginCtrl. If I make request in any other controller its without this header.

As soon as I create other $http request in other controllers I need it work there. Is there some nice way how to set it for each controller or I have to set it at load of each controller  from cookie?

Answer (score 2):

Angular provides you with `interceptors` that can manipulate any $http call from your application.
Look at this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

**example**

```
appName.config(["$httpProvider", ($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) => {
                $httpProvider.interceptors.push(() => { 

                        return {
                            'request': (config) => {

                           //retrieving a token from localStorage for example
                               var token = localStorage.getItem("token"); 
                               if (token)
                                   config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;

                                return config;
                            },
                            'responseError': (rejection) => {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have create Services for every controller

```
module.run(function($http, $rootScope, subHeaderService) {
  subHeaderService.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
  //subHeaderService.auth= 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'; you can use like this
});

app.service('subHeaderService', function() {
    return {};
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'subHeaderService',
    //subHeaderService.auth     
    //call here 
]);
```

or you can use interceptors.